# nodejs jade conditional extend

Tags: node.js, layout, conditional-statements, express, pug

I would like to make my Jade page extend different layouts, depending on a condition. So my code looks like this:

```
if myConditionVariable
  extends layout1
else
  extends layout2  
block content
  p here goes my content!
```

Now this does not work. It seems as if only the last defined extends will be respected, regardless of the conditions. I also tried dynamically defining the templatename, such as

```
extends myLayoutNameVariable
```

and set the myLayoutNameVariable in different manners (express dynamic helper function, set it as var, local var etc...)

Is there any other solution for conditional layouts or can someone tell me what i am doing wrong?

Cheers, simon

Comment: Did you mean `- if myConditionVariable` — see that minus in front of `if`? (Same for `else` branch.) Also, you probably mean `append block` or something.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This seems to be an issue that's still open on [github](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/issues/520).

Comment: thanks for the hint! Apparently the same goes for includes, as the layouts and includes are resolved at compile time, not runtime.

Answer (score 11):

So, a slightly less intrusive way to deal with this is to change the layout itself.

I added a bit of middleware, and the rest flows..

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    res.locals.isAjax = req.headers['x-requested-with'] && 
        req.headers['x-requested-with'] === 'XMLHttpRequest';
    next();
});
```

Now that this is set, "isAjax" is available to jade.

In my "layout.jade" (the template you will extend *from*), I do this:

```
- if(!isAjax)
  doctype 5
    html
      head
      body
        block content
        block scripts
- else
  block content
  block scripts
```

I have stripped out the other elements of the full layout.jade for (hopefully) clarity.

Finally, my normal views that extend layout.jade work without modification (this jade template includes both cases).

```
extends layout.jade
  .container.
     This is text will be wrapped for a non-ajax request, 
     but not for an ajax request.
```

Comment: Does this affect performance at all? When I looked at the issue on github linked above it seemed like TJ said Express wouldn't cache the pages. Sorry to raise a old question from the dead.

Comment: @mshindal - I'm not sure how to answer your question, there's really multiple parts to this: 1) JADE compilation happens the same as before, so more template code, but not really a huge impact. 2) Depends on how caching is configured, if you're using ETags, you'll need to account for this header in generating the etag, but honestly, I think this solution is orthogonal to caching concerns. So.. my answer would be "no, it doesn't impact performance"

Comment: Just so you know, express exposes `req.xhr` which checks for the `x-requested-with` header for you ;)

Comment: Well, there you go @chev! -- even easier.

Answer (score 6):

I hope it's not too late but i ran across this issue and I think I figured out a workaround:

1. Make a layout.jade that conditionaly includes both layouts:

   ```
   layout.jade:

   if conditionalVariable
       include firstLayout.jade
   else
       include otherLayout
   ```
2. In your view, extend `layout.jade`, and define `conditionalVariable` in the controller (`true`/`false`):

   ```
   view.jade:

   extends layout

   block content
       p here goes my content!
   ```
3. [Disco](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UkSPUDpe0U8)!

Comment: What about extends, I tried for extends firstLayout but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Can you do something like:

```
if myConditionVariable
  p test
```

?

If not, do you pass `myConditionVariable` correct when you tell to render that view? A short example for this:

```
app.get "/", (req, res) ->
  res.render "index",
    myConditionVariable: true
```

Comment: He's passing it correctly. If not, there would be error saying `myConditionVariable not defined`.