# jade extends different layouts based on a if case

Tags: node.js, layout, express, pug, extends

I can't get this to work, it always takes the else even if i put `if true` in it. I've googled a lot about this and it looks like that in jade's earlier versions there was a `layout` option and now they have removed it in favor of `extends`. But there is no way to change an `extend`?

```
if true
  extends index
else
  extends widget

block body
  p Test

# widget.jade gets rendered because the if is ignored
```

Comment: [maybe it will help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041168/nodejs-jade-conditional-extend)

Comment: thank you, i could use this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041168/nodejs-jade-conditional-extend/21239891#21239891)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [nodejs jade conditional extend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041168/nodejs-jade-conditional-extend)