# View engine that supports both ajax and direct calls

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, viewengine

I'm looking for a way to serve a template in Node.js (Express) both "normally" rendered as HTML and rendered as JSON, if it was requested with ajax.

Let's say I have a template like this in swig:

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}
{% block title %}Default Page{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
  <p>Hi, {{ name }}.</p>
{% endblock %}
```

Now, if I make a normal request with my browser, swig will render the file with `layout.html` as layout.
But if I make a request with ajax (or a paramater like `?partial`), I would like to have the blocks as JSON, without it being rendered in `layout.html`:

```json
{
  "title": "Default Page",
  "body": "<p>Hi, Dave.</p>"
}
```

The choose of swig was arbitrary, it could be any view engine that supports layout inheritance with blocks.

I searched through the docs of swig and Nunjucks for a simple way to influence the template rendering on a request-basis, but I didn't came up with an idea (without it being a total overkill).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Simplified my answer more to your specific use-case:

You can easily accomplish this through the use of a "middleware override".

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  var oldRender = res.render.bind(res);
  res.render = function (viewName, viewData) {
    viewData.xhr = req.xhr;
    if (!req.xhr) {
      res.render(viewName, viewData);
    } else {
      res.render(viewName, viewData, function (err, renderedView) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        res.json({
          url: req.url, // In case you want to use the HTML5 history API to update the URL in-place in the client's browser.
          title: viewData.title,
          view: renderedView
        });
      });
    }
  };
});
```

<strike>Then ideally your view engine should be able to do something like:</strike>

```
{% if !xhr %} 
  {% extends 'layout.html' %}
{% endif %}
```

Now when you call `res.render('someView', { title: 'some title' });` it will either compile a full view and send it down or if it's an XHR request then it will send down a JSON blob with the request URL, the page title, and the rendered view as a string. Then you can update the page dynamically on the client.

If your template engine does not support conditional `extends` then you can work around this with a little "hack" as it were. You'll need two views (pseudo-code):

```
// someView
<p>Hi, {{ name }}</p>

// someView_full
{% extends 'layout.html' %}
{% block title %}Default Page{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
  {% include 'someView' %}
{% endblock %}
```

Then modify your middleware function to append `"_full"` to the view name when it's not an AJAX request.

```
 if (!req.xhr) {
   res.render(viewName + "_full", viewData);
 } else { ... }
```

---

**Edit:** There is another way that avoids creating a second little bridge view or even having to wrap every `extends` in a condition for every one of your views. I found this method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18116483/498624). Turns out you can conditionally create content blocks in the layout file, making this possible:

```
// layout
{% if !xhr %}
  <html>
    <head>
      <title>My Awesome Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      {% block body %}{% endblock %}
    </body>
  </html>
{% else %}
  {% block body %}{% endblock %}
{% endif %}
```

This way the layout file will be the one that decides whether or not to include the surrounding markup.

PS - `req.xhr` only works if the client framework making the AJAX request includes the [`x-requested-with` header set to "XMLHttpRequest"](https://github.com/strongloop/express/blob/1e6d2654a284f00c4bb92e201d87982e3dfb9a7c/lib/request.js#L448-L451) (hint: most do). If your framework does not include that header then there may be an option you can toggle, or at the very least you should be able to set custom headers and include it yourself.

You could use a query string variable like you suggested in your question, but using this request header is the standard convention for communicating to the server that the request is AJAX and is usually turned on by default in client-side frameworks. That's why Express has `req.xhr` built in :)

Comment: So you're loading a different view, okay! That can be useful. But this results pretty much in a big redundancy. I'm not quite sure if I want to duplicate my content. :/

Comment: It's not a duplication. That's the whole point. It's an extra little file that both `extends` the layout file and `includes` the content file. The meat of the view lives in the partial view file and then only gets loaded into a full document if the `someView_full` file is rendered, which then sucks in the partial view `someView`.

Comment: [Here is an example](https://goo.gl/3Oz1kO) of the middleware helper. That function runs when I call `res.renderView`. You can see [here](https://goo.gl/yeORnF) that the layout file has a content block. You can see [here](https://goo.gl/kF6Jf0) the file that bridges the layout file and the partial view. Notice that it is a simple `include`, not a duplicate view. And finally, [here](https://goo.gl/NdzDV4) is the partial view. No duplicated content. Just an extra little "bridge" view between the partial and the layout.

Comment: Notice in [my example](https://goo.gl/3Oz1kO) helper function that when it's AJAX I actually call `res.json` and send down a JSON object with the page title, the view markup as a string, and a couple other things relevant to my app. Then on the client I insert the partial view and set the page title dynamically using that data, which is exactly what you are trying to do in your question yes?

Comment: I'm sorry, I just focused on the "There's another view-file" and read over the include. To be honest, it feels a bit hacky and I don't know if I will implement it like this in my project, **but** it works.

Comment: Well I did say in my answer that the need for the bridge file was precisely because of the way Jade views compile; they don't allow conditional `extends`, otherwise the bridge view wouldn't be required at all. It's entirely possible that your template engine can do what Jade can't. I know there are some that can conditionally extend a layout file, Jade just isn't one of them. You call it "hacky", I call it [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) ;). Even if it is *hacky*, it's a Jade hack and you aren't using Jade. The point of my answer was the middleware override pattern.

Comment: Please calm down. I didn't say your answer doesn't work. As you said, there's the need for the bridge in Jade. And the other view engines I would like to use don't have conditional extends either. So, in my case(s) there would be the need for the bridge too. I would like to use this for a boilerplate project structure, and you have to admit, a boilerplate with this bridge isn't quite as optimal as it could be. A great solution would be to extend the view engine to support this.

Comment: Calm down? I think you're projecting buddy. Good luck.

Comment: I already upvoted your answer because it works and I will accept the answer if nobody has a better solution. So please be patient. My attitude isn't "Yep, it works, so that's what I will do", instead I try to get at the bottom of the problem and search for a solution there... and the bottom of the problem is that you can't change the extend.

Comment: At what point did I implore you to accept the answer? I was just trying to help you out because I've encountered this situation before and spent a lot of time figuring it out. Quit taking my feedback as an *"I'm right and you should click the damn check mark already."* I even used emoticons to convey my candid tone. I'll leave you to it. PS - I re-wrote my entire answer to make it more clear and specific to your use-case (out of the kindness of my heart, nothing more.).

Comment: I just found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18116483/498624). You might find that idea interesting. Solves the need for the bridge file. Just splits your layout into two logic paths.

Comment: I think I'll use this. Also it has a few benefits compared to my original idea, that the "blocks to json"-part should work automatically. Thank you!

Comment: I just found out nunjucks (which is quite similar to swig) [supports conditional extends](https://github.com/mozilla/nunjucks/issues/39#issuecomment-47550285). At the moment with the use of a variable, the next release will support it with a normal `if`/`else` statement.